# Is Mingw compiler generates dll with relative path.?

Tags: dll, makefile, mingw32

Compiler: Mingw GCC compiler

In make file I specified src directory location like below..

```
dirsrc = ./src
```

So here I mentioned current directory. The problem is the generated DLL having the **Absolute path** to the source directory. Is there any way to notify the compiler which should be relative.?

Because I am generating this DLL with Codecoverage information. If I moved my full project structure to somewhere means while simulating the DLL to target, at that time the DLL refers to the absolute path of the source directory.

I need the DLL with relative path to the source directory.? How do I write the make file with relative path to the source directory?

**The real problem is**,

I am doing code coverage analysis using gcov.
I followed following steps:

1.) I compiled my program with GNU CC options: `-fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage'.
2.) I got 2 additional file with suffix *.bb and *.bbg in same directory
3.) Running the program will cause profile output to be generated.

For each source file compiled with `-fprofile-arcs', an accompanying` .da' file will be placed in the source directory. The name of the `.da' file is stored as an *_absolute pathname_* in the resulting object file. This path name is derived from the source file name by substituting a` .da' suffix.

The problem here is that I am compiling on one machine and running on a seperate machine. Each '.da' file has absoulte pathname in the resulting object file. So it does not find same path on another machine.

Is it possible to have `fprofile-arcs` and any other profiling-related options in GCC to have file names relative rather than absolute.
please let me asap.! thanks in advance.

Comment: This does not look like a makefile problem to me, but a matter of properly instructing the code coverage tool (if possible). Which tool are you using and did you consult its documentation?

Comment: Hello Reinier, thanks for ur feedback. pls look at the updated correct issue definition. let me know ur suggesstions.!!